# Shuffle function when on click button

Tags: javascript, php, html, shuffle

Whenever i refresh the page the words shuffle. For example "May I# know# your name?". It shuffle to "know May I your name". I want it the exact correct sentences to print out with your the "#" like" May I know your name?" After clicking the SHUFFLE button it will then shuffle.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
      <div id="cardContainer" draggable="true"></div>
<style>
      .box {
          width:200px;
          height:20px;
          padding:10px;
          border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
          display: inline-block;
      }
      .mover{
          color:red; 
          background-color: yellow;
          width:auto ; 
          font-size: 30px ; 
          border: 2px;
      }
      #id1 {
         color:black; 
         background-color: #2BFFB6; 
         width:150px ;
         font-size: 40px ;
         border: 1px;
         display: inline;
         margin: 20px;
     }
     #id2 {
         color:black; 
         background-color: #2BFFB6; 
         width:150px ;
         font-size: 40px ;
         border: 1px;
         display: inline;
         margin: 20px;
    }
    #id3 {
        color:black;
        background-color: #2BFFB6; 
        width:150px ;
        font-size: 40px ; 
        border: 1px;
        display: inline;
        margin: 20px;
   }
   #id4 {
       color:black; 
       background-color: #2BFFB6;
       width:150px ; 
       font-size: 40px ; 
       border: 1px;
       display: inline;
       margin: 20px;
   }
  #id5 {
      color:black; 
      background-color: #2BFFB6;
      width:150px ; 
      font-size: 40px ; 
      border: 1px;
      display: inline;
      margin: 20px;
 }
 #id6 {
      color:black; 
      background-color: #2BFFB6; 
      width:150px ; 
      font-size: 40px ;
      border:1px;
      display: inline;
      margin: 20px;
}
```

```
 <div id>Is this draggable and droppable?</div>
 </body>
 <head>
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");

    if (!mysql_select_db("login")) {
        echo "Unable to select go database " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT table
    FROM   se
    WHERE  id = 1";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $output =  $row["full"];
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>
    <script>
       var js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";
       var div_id = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10'];
       var box_id = ['box1','box2','box3','box4','box5','box6','box7','box8','box9','box10'];
    var original=js_var.split("#");
    var balls90= js_var.split("#");

    function getNumbers() {
         var player1 = new Array();
         balls90.sort(function() {
         return Math.random() - .25;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
        document.writeln('<div id="+box_id[i]+" class="box" droppable="true" ondrop="drop(event)"         
        ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>');
     }

    for (var i = 0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
        player1.push(balls90[i]);
    }

    }

    getNumbers();

    function dragWord(dragEvent){
        dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/html",         
        dragEvent.target.textContent+"|"+dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
    }


    function dropWord(dropEvent){ 
        var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html"); 
        var dropItems = dropData.split("|"); 
        var prevElem = document.getElementById(dropItems[1]); 
        prevElem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent = dropEvent.target.textContent; 
        dropEvent.target.textContent = dropItems[0]; 
        dropEvent.preventDefault(); 
    } 

    function allowDrop(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
    }   


    function drag(ev) {
       ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
     //var data_content=document.getElementById(data).innerText;
    //alert('The selected text is: ' + data_content + '.');
    }

    </script>
        <button id="shuffle" type="button">SHUFFLE</button>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
var textDiv = document.getElementById('text');
document.getElementById('shuffle').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var words = textDiv.innerText.split(' ');
    var len = words.length;
    var result = '';
    textDiv.innerText = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        var randIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * (words.length)));
        result += words[randIndex] + ' ';
        words.splice(randIndex, 1);
    }
    textDiv.innerText = result;
}, false);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weeklyTea/48gqa/

Comment: The sentence from my database can be retrieved. I need show the exact sentence first, after clicking the shuffle button the sentence will then shuffle. And the code I have is that I didn't have any sentence in the html file. The sentence that shuffle is written in JavaScript. Currently, what it appear now is the sentence which it takes from the database which is already shuffle.

Comment: So, you receive already shuffled sentence from database to variable js_var, and you want set words in sentence in correct order? In this case you should receive information about correct order from database. For example you can keep sentence's words with their sequence number in object like this: `var sentence = {'this':1, 'expample':3, 'is':2}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
    var txt=document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
       var splittxt=txt.split(" ");
       splittxt.sort(function(){
           return Math.round(Math.random());
       });  
       document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML=splittxt.join(" ");    
    },false);
}
</script>
```